# Linux kernel BUG() sometimes does not print stack trace and regs

Tags: linux, kernel, assert

We have a kernel module that uses BUG() in case of failed assertions. The module is for ARM architecture. Typically the registers and stack trace are printed on serial console when BUG() is used. In some places, however, BUG() does not print stack trace, the last line seen on console is printk from the assert macro and than system hangs.

What are the possible reasons for stack trace and registers to not be printed on console? Is it a feature that can be accidentally disabled?

P.S: On this platform the crash inside BUG() is done with `*(int *)0 = 0;`